# How to show a hidden div with javascript when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not really familiar with jquery, but am trying to get a simple animated gif to show when a form is submitted. When clicking 'submit' to upload an image I want to show gif so that users know that image is being uploaded. The submit button has an id="submit" and also an onClick="return confirm('message')"

I have the div code containing the gif:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none">

    <img src="images/hand_timer2.gif" alt="loading" />

</div>
```

which is hidden. And it does show if I remove the style. Fair enough. But when I try to show it with the following javascript it doesn't show:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#loading').show();

        }); 
    });
```

I have

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"    
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in a separate PHP header file. As far as I can see it's the only reference to jquery library, but I do have other javascript codes that all work. I just can't get this one to work. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and why I can't get the div to show gif when clicking submit?

Comment: Just FYI. You are using a really old version of jQuery. The current version is 1.8.3.

Comment: What does you're html look like?

Comment: Can you show your HTML code as well? Put a log or alert inside your submit function so that you can be sure that is being called correctly when your form is submitted. If it is, then check to make sure that your loading element is correct from the same scope.

Comment: yeah thanks. Just updated. Still no joy. But thanks

Comment: On clicking button try first displaying image and then submit form inside of `setTimeout`. This will take form submitting out of context allowing image to display

Comment: HTML please! Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link.

Comment: Never use a `click` event to detect that a form is submitted, it can be submitted using enter, or the space bar also. Use the `submit` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem could be that your inline `onClick="return confirm('message')"` prevent the click-event from reaching your click-event listener attached with jQuery - not sure though. Anyhow, instead of listening for a click-event on the submit-button, I would listen for the submit event on the form, that will fire when the form is actually submitted (a form can usually be posted by other means than clicking the submit button as well - through the Enter key for instance).

```
$('#idOfYourForm').on("submit", function () {
    $('#loading').show();
});
```

**Side note:**

You don't close the style attribute properly on your loading div (notice that the `>` is blue):

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none>
```

Comment: This won't show the div for too long, since the submit is sending a request to the server, you need to `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks Christofer. That's it. It was the inline onClick. Your changes sorted it. Thanks. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JuanMendes Actually, since OP is saying that he wants to show the div becuase the user is uploading a file, it may very well be shown for a while, while the file is being uploaded. Also he shouldn't definitely not `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` since that would prevent the form from being posted at all (I don't believe OP is doing an Ajax-request).

Comment: @juan—so the user will see an image saying the form is being submitted forever, because submit was cancelled.